# How can I remotely control a VirtualBox virtual machine using VNC?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vnc, remote-access

I'm virtualizing an Elementary OS Loki using VirtualBox 5.1.8 on Windows 7 Enterprise, and I want to remotely control this VM from a Windows 10 Pro using VNC. I'm inexperienced in VMs and remote control, so a more detailed explanation may be necessary.

Obs.: I've seen this before:[How to connect to VirtualBox remote desktop client using VNC?](https://superuser.com/questions/322803/how-to-connect-to-virtualbox-remote-desktop-client-using-vnc) The problem is that the configuration is different. I'm trying to access a Linux guest in a Windows host, from another Windows. This person tried to access a Windows guest in a Linux host, from Mac. And I saw that in this specific case there was some sort of port issue. So, I suppose my specific configuration may demand some specific details that someone more experienced can tell.

Comment: As noted in the linked question VirtualBox does not support VNC.  Since you're wanting to control the VM from Windows PC, I would recommend the built in RDP support.  Otherwise if you must use VNC you will have to install a VNC server on the guest machine.

Comment: I second the rdp approach.  See this for more info https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html