# Which other Extension Packs for VirtualBox are available?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, extension

The default solution to access VMs outside the guest with VirtualBox seems to be VRDP provided by the VirtualBox Extension Pack. But that is not free to use in a commercial use case and pretty expensive in my opinion as well: Things easily cost ~ 5'500 € even in case one e.g. only wants to host one VM-server accessed by one or two admins.

> Personal Use and/or Educational Use expressly exclude any use of the Product for commercial purposes or to operate or run a business, organization, governmental organization, or educational institution.
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack Enterprise Named User Plus licenses must be purchased in an initial quantity of at least 100.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ

From my experience, something like RDP is necessary from time to time in case VMs don't come up, need to be upgraded and run into trouble and one lands in rescue shells etc. RDP makes things simply easier.

I've already read about [VNC](https://superuser.com/a/1095851/308859), but things don't sound [good](https://superuser.com/questions/1400486/virtualbox-vnc-extension-pack-for-windows-host-exists). While Oracle provides a distinct [chapter for 3rd party extension packs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#otherextpacks) and mentions VNC in that, I never came across any other extension pack in practice.

**So, is there some list or stuff for which 3rd party extension packs are available out there?**

The ultimate goal of course would be to find replacements for that of Oracle in case one can't use that due to license restrictions.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I'd either a) RDP/VNC into the virtual machine _host_ and use GUI tools to attach to console, or b) question the whole idea of using VirtualBox for anything else than personal environments...

Comment: Note to self: The easiest way to work around the license limitation really is to install VirtualBox with its own GUI. This allows attaching to VMs started `headless` by simply choosing the VM and press some "Show" button or however it's named. It's simply the one which would otherwise be sued to start the VM initially. that does not only seem to work for `separate` VM, but plain headless one as well. It's documented to use the same technology anyway: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm